# AWS EC2 - WampServer LocalHost "The Page Cannot Be Displayed"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wamp, wampserver

The security group for my EC2 instance has TCP 80 and 443 open inbound/outbound.

Installed the latest version of WampServer on Windows Server 2016 instance, when I run WAMP the icon in the bottom right is orange in color, when I try to navigate to localhost in my browser I receive

> The Page Cannot Be Displayed

There should be a test page which shows WampServer is up and running, clearly something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must have forgot to open the Port in Windows Server Firewall , Open Ports In Windows Firewall and then AWS Security Group, it should work fine.

Hope this Helps

Comment: Forgot to delete this, but since you answered this was indeed the solution.